# How to change Vim's command type mode programmatically?

Tags: vim, scripting, keyboard-shortcuts, key-mapping

Is there a simple way to switch from one command type mode to another without loosing the current command line?

In my `~/.vimrc` file I remap the `<space>` and `<c-space>` character, coming from, to:

1. N,V,O => :
2. I => :
3. : => / => ?

The code that accomplishes the above behavior is:

```
function! s:ModMapSpaceChar()
  noremap <unique> <space> :
  map <unique> <nul> <c-space>
  map! <unique> <nul> <c-space>
  noremap <unique> <c-space> /
  inoremap <unique> <c-space> <c-o>:
  cnoremap <unique> <c-space> <c-\>eg:ToggleCmdTypes()<cr><c-c>@"
  let g:CmdTypes={':' : '/', '/' : '?', '?': ':'}
  function! g:ToggleCmdTypes()
    let a=getcmdtype()
    let b=get(g:CmdTypes, a, a)
    let c=getcmdline()
    let @"=b . c
    return ''
  endfunction
endfunction

call s:ModMapSpaceChar()
```

What bothers me in my approach is the impure function `g:ToggleCmdTypes`. It should ideally return the command that it currently assigns to the `"` register. The resulting command shall then be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the detour through the register, you could probably also use `feedkeys()` for this, to avoid clobbering the register. This has only the disadvantage that it won't work when recorded and replayed as a macro.

In general, I would recommend to re-think your general approach; I don't see how it's useful to switch command-line modes like that. Who starts a search only to realize half-way through that he wants that executed as a command instead?!

Comment: I _very often_ want to use the incremental hilighting to get feedback while building a regular expression for a `:s` command (or, conversely, go back to `/` to get the benefit of incremental hilighting to figure out where I screwed up my regex)

Comment: @Random832: `:s` re-uses the last search, anyway, if you omit the pattern. For the other direction, you can insert the last command line via `<C-r>:`.

Comment: Right but then I don't have it in the command line if I want to modify it for subsequent `:s`'s - I'd be locked into doing / again then :s//... again, and can't see my capture groups in front of me.

Comment: @Random832: You can use `<C-r>/` to insert the pattern, too. But if you like the switch function better, go ahead and use it!